# Modify specific bit in byte

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I need to modify (!not toggle XOR!) specific bit in byte value. I have:

1. source `byte` (e.g. `b11010010`);
2. index of bit to modify (e.g. `4`);
3. new value of bit (`0` or `1`).

Now, what I need. If new value is `0`, then bit[4] must be set to `0`. If new value is `1`, then bit[4] must be set to `1`.

General part:

```
var bitIndex = 4;
var byte = b11010010;
var mask = 1 << bitIndex;
var newValue = 1;
```

This is the easiest way to do this:

```
if(newValue == 1)
    byte |= mask; // set bit[bitIndex]
else
    byte &= ~mask; // drop bit[bitIndex]
```

Another way allows to do this without `if else` statement, but look to hard to understand:

```
byte = byte & ~mask | (newValue << bitIndex) & mask
```

Here, first `AND` drops `bit[bitIndex]`, second `AND` calculates new value for `bit[bitIndex]`, and `OR` set `bit[bitIndex]` to calculated value, not matter is it `0` or `1`.

Is there any easier way to set specific bit into given value?

Comment: Please pick a specific language. There may be very different solutions depending on a specific language.

Comment: Just move that to a separate function like `SetBit(byte target, bool value)`. It's already easy enough as it is - no reason to search for even "easier" way.

Comment: That "hard to understand" way is pretty easy. There's a shorter expression but it's more obscure: `value ^ ((value ^ (newValue << bitIndex)) & mask)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is:

```
byte ^= (-newValue ^ byte) & (1 << n);
```

Bit number n will be set if newValue == 1, and cleared if newValue == 0

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I need. ))

Comment: @user2123532 Thanks so much for the accept vote but could you please up-vote the answer too.  Upvoted and accepted answers show up higher in search results and have more potential to help others.  :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't because of reputation. Need 15 at least to vote up.

Comment: @LJH Thanks. Will vote up as soon as get minimal required reputation. :)

Comment: This is more complicated than the version in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt and yet the OP accepted my answer... must have suited his needs.

Answer (score 3):

`(newValue << bitIndex)` only has a single bit set, there's no need for `& mask`.

So you have just 5 operations.

```
byte = byte & ~(1 << bitIndex) | (newValue << bitIndex); // bitIndex'th bit becomes newValue
```

It's still complex enough to be worth a comment, but easy to see that the comment is correct because it's two easily recognized operations chained together (unlike the current accepted answer, which requires every reader to sit down and think about it for a minute)